# Best data format to store features?

Tags: database, deep-learning

I am using CNN network to extract features, I extract features from the layer before final full connected layer. They have dimension of 4096 and the size of data is about 1 million. 
I want to store these features on the serve for further usage. But I am not sure which data format shall I chose to use. Pickle? CSV? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HDF5 format. It is commonly used in different deep learning frameworks like caffe or tensorflow for example. Here you an check an example on how to use it in python: [hdf5 example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/test/test_data/generate_sample_data.py).